# Clang function cursor return type

Tags: clang, clang++, libclang

I am trying to get the type of parameters and type of return of a C function.

For example I have function:

```
int addTwoIntegers(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
}
```

What I need is: int (int, int)

I am using clang frontend to generate AST. Currently I have:

```
CXString cursorVariables = clang_getCursorDisplayName( cursor );
string methodDecl      = clang_getCString( cursorVariables );
cout << methodDecl << '\n';
```

It gives me:

```
addTwoIntegers(int, int)
```

and nothing about the type of the return value. My question is how should I get the return type of function from cursor CXCursor_FunctionDecl?

Comment: `cout` <- Looks like this is C++ and not C

Comment: I am generating clangAST for C file

Comment: @FarrukhNabiyev: I would be sympathetic to including the C tag if understanding and answering the question involved some question or puzzle about C, but it does not look like that so far. Maybe some rudimentary C knowledge is needed to understand the function declaration, but that is well within the knowledge of anybody working with Clang internals. So the C tag is not needed here and would like just be noise to most people who follow it. The question primarily needs Clang knowledge, not C knowledge. We do not really even need the C++ tag.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have removed c++ tag.